# Task Scheduler won't run ClickOnce Application

Tags: c#, clickonce, windows-task-scheduler

I have written a console application that downloads a file from an FTP site. I published it as a ClickOnce application. The application works perfectly when launched from my user account on the server where it's deployed.

I tried to set up a task scheduler task that launches the program using the SYSTEM account. The task runs but the application never launches. There are no errors noted in the history of the task scheduler. The "Run with highest privileges" option is selected.

I've run a test batch file script from the SYSTEM account in task scheduler and it runs fine.

I also tried to run the ClickOnce application using the NETWORK SERVICE account in task scheduler to no avail. I made sure the accounts have access to the folder containing the clickonce application. I also tried using the "Start In" field and leaving it blank with the same result.

I copied the entire debug folder to the server and was able to get the task scheduler to launch the .exe build. The task scheduler ran that as expected but it won't run the compiled .application. Is there a particular way clickonce applications need to be published using .net8 to be able to run in task scheduler?

Comment: Did you try running under your user account in Task Scheduler? My guess would be that you installed the ClickOnce application for your user, not for every user. If you install for a specific user then running a scheduled task as that user would probably work but running the task under a different account would require the application to be installed for all users.

Comment: I did run it under my user account so it would've installed under my profile. If that is the problem, how would I install it for all users so the SYSTEM and NETWORK SERVICE accounts would have it? I'm assuming an MSI of some sort?

Comment: I don't really use ClickOnce and I was under the impression that you could choose whether to install for the current user or for all users (if the current user was an admin) but it looks like that is not the case. If you want to do so, it does look like you'll need to use a more conventional installer. Which you use is up to you but the most obvious option is to install the VS extension for Setup Projects and create a Windows Installer package that way.

Comment: Note that you really should run the scheduled task under your account as a test, to make sure that that is the issue.

Comment: `.application` is not an actual application, it's just a link and will not work with Scheduler. You need it to lanuch the `.exe` file. Also ClickOnce is intended for sinlge-user installations, not system-wide.

Comment: I published the application as a single file executable and set task scheduler to run the .exe file instead and that solved my problem. Thank you everyone for your help.